# python zlib array decompression problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

I have a a couple of big arrays that I compress with zlib like this:

```
array = zlib.compress(array)
```

after i decompress the array again and try to print it I just get garbage

```
array = zlib.decompress(array)
print array
```

the garbage:`���^�/? ........`

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean arrays? shouldn't it take a string as input?

Comment: `zlib.compress` takes a **string** argument and returns a string, ditto for `zlib.decompress`.  What type is your `array`?  If anything **but** a string (which would be weird given the variable name), you'll have to serialize it into a string (`pickle`, whatever) before compressing, and de-serialize it back after decompressing (types from the `array` *module* of the standard library do offer faster approaches).  So: what's `type(array)`?

Comment: it is a numpy array so yes i had to pickle it first thanks for the help!